# Fractional/Integer Based integrals

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, soft-question, indefinite-integrals, big-list

I see a lot of integrals on this page that involve the fractional/integer component of a Real variable $x$. I was wondering what applications these are founded in?

Comment: Measure theory? Real analysis?

Comment: On which page...?

Comment: @Digamma - this page... which in the context of the post is MSE. Sorry for any confusion caused.

Comment: $y=\{x\}$ is the [Sawtooth wave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sawtooth_wave), you compute integrals with it to find the amplitudes of its harmonics, its Fourier coefficients.

Comment: Post it as an answer and I'll award you the points.

Answer (score 2):

$y=\{x\}$ is the [Sawtooth wave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sawtooth_wave), you compute integrals with it to find the amplitudes of its harmonics, its Fourier coefficients.

In the Wikipedia [article for Floor and ceiling functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions#Applications) you can find other applications. Some of the ones listed there are , for example, in analytic number theory, in formulas expressing the Euler constant or the Riemann theta function.

They might appear when working with the Gauss transformation $T(x)=\frac{1}{x}-\lfloor\frac{1}{x}\rfloor$, used in the study of continued fractions and rational approximation, and [proving that it is Ergodic with respect to its invariant measure](https://personalpages.manchester.ac.uk/staff/charles.walkden/magic/lecture04.pdf#page=11) $\mu(B)=\frac{1}{\ln(2)}\int_{B}\frac{dt}{1+t}$.

Comment: It's forcing me to wait 24 hours. Will award tomorrow this time.

Answer (score 0):

Another very useful property of the floor-, ceiling- and nearest integer function is that they are locally constant. That means that for any integrable function $f$ of a real variable, and integers $a<b$, you have
$$\int_a^bf([x])\,\mathrm{d}x=\sum_{k=a}^{b-1}f(k).$$
Here $[x]$ is a placeholder for either the floor-, ceiling or nearest integer function. Also the integral (and sum) need not be bounded; in stead of $a$ and $b$ you can take $-\infty$ and $\infty$, respectively.